# Full wave bridge circuit voltage calculator

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, bridge-rectifier

A transformer with a 12.6 Vrms secondary supplies the AC voltage for a full-wave bridge circuit. The output goes to a 1000 microfarad capacitor in parallel with a 4.7 kilo ohm resistive load.

Compute the DC voltage and current on the load.

I tried to solve this but all the formulas require the frequency to be known, which is not given in the question.

Is there any other formula that can help?

Comment: Use the grid frequency for your country and state in your answer that that's the assumption you are working on. If you want confirmation of your answer then show your calculations in the question.

Answer (score 1):

> The output to a 1000 micro Farad in parallel with a 4.7 kilo ohm
>   resistive load.

The time constant is 4.7 seconds and therefore it can be assumed that any reasonable AC frequency from 1 Hz upwards is going to give you the same answer. In other words, you only need to know the frequency if the load is heavy AND you are required to calculate ripple content on the DC output from the bridge/capacitor.

> Is there any other formula that can help?

Can you take it from here?